# How to find javascript memory leak issues , in a web app hosted in QT web view

Tags: javascript, qt, memory-leaks

I have a web app that is running on device, hosted on QT web view. I am facing a lot of crashes as free heap memory is unavailable. The qWebVView webkit , has a profiler with limited capabilities, hence I can't take heap snapshots and compare. Is there any other method to detect JavaScript memory leak issues in this case

Qt version : 5.3

Comment: You should consider switching to [QtWebEngine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-index.html) if possible. Also upgrading to the latest Qt version (5.8) can help with the memory leak problems.

Comment: The webkit included in your version of Qt has memory leaks :(

Comment: Can you guys point me to a source or document.